# Cyclic type definition in OCaml #2

Tags: ocaml

As said in ([Cyclic type definition in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093873/cyclic-type-definition-in-ocaml)) this cannot be defined:

```
type t = int * t
```

because it'll cause an infinite loop is the type checking and the value construction.

But this is legal:

```
type t = Node of int * t
type t = { value : int * t; }
```

It is still impossible to construct value of these type, but they can be defined.

Now, why this cannot be defined ?

```
type t = int * (unit -> t)
```

and this ?

```
type t = int * (unit -> t) list
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule says that there must be a constructor between the type and the internal recursive reference. So `Node` and the `{ value : ... }` record types are constructors.

You can define all these types if you turn on `-rectypes`. There is no problem in type checking (contrary to what you say).

```
$ rlwrap ocaml -rectypes
        OCaml version 4.03.0

# type t = int * t;;
type t = int * t
# type t = int * (unit -> t);;
type t = int * (unit -> t)
# type t = int * (unit -> t) list;;
type t = int * (unit -> t) list
```

Comment: Thx. Just for knowledge. What prevent `fun () -> ...`, `[...]` and `Some ...` to be added to this rule ? Because they're other type and the compiler is not brave enough ?

Comment: The rule exists just to prevent the inference of types that are much more likely to be errors than desirable types. So I would assume that experience indicates that disallowing these cases is the most helpful in finding errors.

Answer (score 3):

On top of Jeffery's answer: you certainly can build values of those two types:

```
# type t = Node of int * t ;;
# let rec x = Node (3, x) ;;
val x : t = Node (3, <cycle>)
```

It's not finite, but that's not a real problem, isn't it? ;)